# Access to specific user S3 bucket using IAM roles and federated users

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

our project aims to create a platform powered by Django in Python which allow users to create instance and retrieve access to their S3 bucket. 
The folders would be stored in our  S3 bucket with S3://User1 , S3://User2 etc...

We understood that we need to use IAM roles when creating the instance, these roles would have variables with the username. 
The question is how can we give to the IAM roles that username as a parameter? 
Do we need to have a federated login using Cognito or other? If yes which Identity Provider would you advise us to use? (We work with Python and Django).

Thank you !

Comment: Point of clarification: *"The s3 buckets would be stored in our bucket"*  Buckets only contain objects.  They do not contain other buckets.

Comment: Yes Thanks I meant objects :) !